# VS Code install on macOS Mojave

Tags: visual-studio-code, failed-installation

I am very new to the coding world. Taking my first class on Python scripting. I am having hitting a roadblock in installing VS Code. I get the package contents view of the app instead of getting a .app file. I have attempted simply adding the .app file extension at which point I get the VS Code icon that I should expect to see, but i get the message it can't open the application. This happens whether I unzip in Downloads, or if I unzip in my Applications folder. I am at a true loss and I have not been able to find the correct search string in order to ascertain what's going wrong. I have never run into this type of issue with app installs on my Mac. If anyone out there can help me to understand, I would be forever grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Brian

Comment: Can you open vscode at all or is it a file associtaion problem?  Are you on m1 or Intel mac and did you pick correct architecture?  Does https://appdividend.com/2018/03/17/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-mac/ help?

Comment: Hello JL.....

No, I can't open it at all. I am on an Intel Mac, mid-2014. 

When I unzip the download it creates a folder called Visual Studio Code, whereas I am aware that it should unpack as Visual Studio Code.app. The folder opens up to a Contents folder with more sub-folders from there. Nowhere to be found is a VS Code.app file. When I change the root folder to a file extension of .app it shifts the folder to look as a singular file with the VS Code icon. When I launch the "file" it says that it can't be opened. That link doesn't help since I don't get the .app file when upacking.

Comment: Hmmm.  Odd.  You certainly shouldn't have to rename an extension .app or the like.  I dont remember what I did to get it working, not much as I remember. https://youtu.be/gdg4Pzn16AA is a video on how to install.  I suggest you restart again from the dwonload:  by the time you’ve messed around a bit who knows whats going on.  Ask Different on stack exhange is more specialized in mac user problems btw.

Comment: https://youtu.be/bJaBHGKHv9A Another youtube.  Just make sure you follow steps carefully.  There are plenty of “install vscode macos” vids.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think PyCharm is way more better for python scripting than VS code even if you are beginner.

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking about however.

Comment: This is for a college class in which I need to use VS Code for all projects. Outside of the class I may very well end up using PyCharm.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @BrianAldridge All I ever used was Windows OS or Linux OS. I think I can't help you bcse I never used Mac OS. But only I could do was give you advice what IDE is maybe more suitable.